# how to set icon for JFrame window and tray

Tags: java, swing

I would like to show my own icon instead of the Java cup in the window.

[image: screenshot of JFrame]

Also when minimized, I would like to display, my own image. How will I be able to do so?

And  where should I position my image relative to the source file?

**[UPDATE]**

I tried but no luck

```
    TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("image/accounting.gif"));

    //setIconImage();

    SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

    try {
        tray.add(trayIcon);
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        System.out.println("TrayIcon could not be added.");
    }
```

Also i tried

```
TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(createImage("images/bulb.gif", "tray icon"));
```

But seriously doubt `createImage(` and even if it is Object don't know what to import.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your `TrayIcon` issue, you can refer below for a solution:

```
public static void createSystemTrayIcon() {

    if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
        SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
        Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
            System.getenv("MY_PROGRAM_HOME") + "game.ico"
        );

        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();

        final MenuItem menuExit = new MenuItem("Quit");

        MouseListener mouseListener =
            new MouseListener() {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
        };

        ActionListener exitListener =
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
                    System.out.println("Exiting...");
                    r.exit(0);
                }
            };

        menuExit.addActionListener(exitListener);
        popup.add(menuExit);

        final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "My program", popup);

        ActionListener actionListener =
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    trayIcon.displayMessage(
                        "My program ",
                        "version: blahblah",
                        TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO
                    );
            }
        };

        trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
        trayIcon.addActionListener(actionListener);
        trayIcon.addMouseListener(mouseListener);

        try {
            tray.add(trayIcon);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            System.err.println("TrayIcon could not be added.");
        }

    } else {
        //  System Tray is not supported
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`JFrame.setIconImage()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setIconImage%28java.awt.Image%29)

Comment: could you please provide an example with tray icon.

Comment: Get used to reading the API documentation, it contains all the necessary information.

Comment: Now i don't know what to import for `TrayIcon`

Answer (score 1):

An example using setIconImages() : (same applies for setIconImage())

```
public MyFrame() {
    initComponents(); //Added by Netbeans
    List<Image> icons  = new ArrayList();
    icons.add(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/example/icons/16/app.png")).getImage());
    icons.add(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/example/icons/32/app.png")).getImage());
    this.setIconImages(icons);
}
```

The clue is in using the "getImage()" in order to return the Image (as ImageIcon can not be used directly in setIconImages() ).

Answer (score 1):

I havent written about tray icon but Finally I found the main issue in setting the jframe icon. Here is my code. It is similar to other codes but here are few things to mind the game.

```
    this.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Icon.png")).getImage());
```

1) Put this code in jframe WindowOpened event

2) Put Image in main folder where all of your form and java files are created e.g.

```
src\ myproject\ myFrame.form
src\ myproject\ myFrame.java
src\ myproject\ OtherFrame.form
src\ myproject\ OtherFrame.java
src\ myproject\ Icon.png
```

3) And most important that name of file is case sensitive that is icon.png won't work but Icon.png.

this way your icon will be there even after finally building your project.