# Java System Tray PopupMenu MenuItem with icons and variable fonts

Tags: java, swing, menuitem, system-tray

As in the title, is there a way to do it?

[The introductory article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/systemtray/) is either misleading or not completed.

Comment: The screenshot in the article shows an icon there, but it does not explain how to do this, yeah.

Comment: You can check my answer as well (except the variable fonts) at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349642/how-to-set-icon-for-jframe-window-and-tray/5354823#5354823

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8864100/758280

Answer (score 1):

Fonts is not a problem so I'm not sure why that is part of the title. Icons is different.

Check out the section from the Swing tutorial [How to Use the System Tray](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html). The tutorial explains the limitations and provides a link to a Bug Id which has some suggestions. I don't know if the suggestion work since I haven't tried them.