# System Tray Pop up menu item with Image(Icon to the MenuItem)

Tags: java, swing, system-tray, jpopupmenu

I read the [system tray tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html) and [this similar Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357713/java-system-tray-popupmenu-menuitem-with-icons-and-variable-fonts) but can't find a good answer.  I want to add an image to menu item in J2SE application.  In the tutorial, `MenuItem` is used, but I couldn't find how to add icons to menu items in SystemTray pop up. If `JMenuItem` is used, icons can easily be placed in `MenuItems`, but there is `MenuItem`.  How can I add an image to my system tray popmenu?

**Updated**Here, I want to add an image to `MenuItem` in the popup menu(not to the SystemTray.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `JPopupMenu` with your `TrayIcon` ([read here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ixmal/archive/2006/05/using_jpopupmen.html)).

> ```
> trayIcon.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
>         public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
>             if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
>                 jpopup.setLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
>                 jpopup.setInvoker(jpopup);
>                 jpopup.setVisible(true);
>             }
>         }
>     });
> ```

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey.It worked well.There was a problem which is the JPopmenu remained even after the mouse left the JPopup.I could comeup with it by adding a mouseListener.(if mouse exited, then JPopup is invisible. :) ). Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

SystemTray have gor implemented simple syntax

[TrayIcon(Image, "Narrative", JPopupMenu);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/SystemTray.html)

there no required add any additional [Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8460383/714968) for displaying [JPopupMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6290045/714968)

Comment: Umm, no there isn't. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html

Comment: @Jeffrey that isn't reall issue, that about quality of Oracle's Java7 API, and reason why use Sun's Java6 API, in some cases equals suicide to read that, btw J2SE application (<= Java5) hasn't implemented SystemTray or TrayIcon, only via JNI (maybe by implement one Jack Daniels is possible some woodoo with JNA & Runtime.exec())

Comment: I was commenting on the lack of a `TrayIcon(Image, String, JPopupMenu)` constructor. `TrayIcon`s can only take `PopupMenu`s as of Java 7.

Comment: Thanks mKorbel.I think that I had to explain more on my question.and I updated.I want to add an image to the `MenuItem` of the popup menu in SystemTray and not Image to the systemTray.

Comment: are you sure because i can't found what you talking about